# Images are not displaying in webpage grid from uploaded image folder

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, use-state, array-map

I'm trying to make a memory match game using reactjs. I have my components and other files in src folder. index.html,style.css and image folder(img, with all images [img folders are inside public folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujHzp.png)to display on the grid) in public folder.All images in img folder is pngs.

I have to display these images in the grid , so I made a Card component for individual images[card component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Usrj.png) and a [cards component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXwXJ.png) for the container. usestate and arraymap function is used to display these images.

When I first tried with just a string 'card' instead of bringing all images into the folder, it worked pretty well and it displayed 'card' in all grids. Then I imported the images folder and it's still showing the grids and its CSS properties, but the images are not loading into the display. I changed the number of images and with respect to that, the number of grids are changing, but the images are not displaying.

[container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzJfQ.png)  is a class in cards component, and card class for card.js. I have no idea what am I missing in these codes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the card component (See props instead of item) as the function parameter.

```
export default function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <img src={props.item.img} alt="" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please do share the code as text and not images next time.
Hope this was helpful.

Comment: It did worked,thanks. about the images, i thought it would shown as just images, didn't noticed it will be links like this, but I'll definitely add codes instead of images from now on.